# Passing a float and a list through a function and distinguishing between them

Tags: python

I would like to make a function that can take a single element or a list as arguments.

```
def Density(m, *vol):
    """
    Inputs:
    m    is the mass.
    vol  is the volume.
    Output:
    rho  is the density.
    """
    for _ in vol:
        if isinstance(vol, float):
            rho = m / _
        elif isinstance(vol, (list,)):
            rho = m / _ * 1000
        else:
            raise ValueError('It is neither a float nor a list, apparently!')
    return rho
```

So, if I define a float and a list

```
flt = 0.25
lst = [0.25, 0.26, 0.24]
```

and try to pass it through `Density`

```
a = Density(50, flt)
b = [Density(50, _) for _ in lst]
```

the error I created appears.

- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: stop using `_` in your loops! `_` is a symbol that means "I'm not going to use this value." Name it something.

Comment: in the second attempt, you're not passing `lst` to the `Density` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: if you do `Density(50, lst)` the type is tuple.

Comment: If you are doing math-y type things to the value that you pass in, I HIGHLY suggest using `numpy` arrays.  In fact, if you use `numpy` arrays instead of lists, that will clear up this whole mess, and it won't be necessary to distinguish between them, since you can math `numpy` arrays...

Comment: Thank you, guys, for setting me straight.

Comment: @Scott, out of curiosity, how would you implement this as an `numpy` array?

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not at all clear what you are attempting to accomplish, so I wouldn't presume to try and implement your class myself.  However, if you define a function `def foo(m, vol):`, then you do not need to loop over the items in `vol` in order to perform multiplication if it is a `numpy` array, so there should be no need to distinguish between floats and arrays.  For example if `vol = numpy.array([0.25, 0.26, 0.24])`, then `m / vol * 1000` is well-defined, and is equal to a new array containing all of the elements of `vol`, divided into `m` and then multiplied by 1000.  Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send arguments with this: `*vol` syntax, they are stored [not in lists, but in tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

> Finally, the least frequently used option is to specify that a function can be called with an arbitrary number of arguments. These arguments will be wrapped up in a tuple (see Tuples and Sequences). Before the variable number of arguments, zero or more normal arguments may occur.

Moreover, because of `Density(m, *vol):` syntax `vol` is always a tuple. So you should check its length. If it is equal to 1, it is a float. If it is more than one - it is a "list".

You should change your loop to this:

```
    for v in vol:
        if len(vol) == 1:
            rho = m / v
        elif len(vol) > 1:
            rho = m / v * 1000
        else:
            raise ValueError('It is neither a float nor a list, apparently!')
```

---

P.S. Your last line is incorrect. Instead of this:

`b = [Density(50, _) for _ in lst]`

you should write this:

`b = [Density(50, *lst)]`

Comment: I noticed that it actually does not work as intended, as it is not able to identify the `float` segment and thus also multiplies `flt` with `1000`. Do you have a solution? I also added `rho = [] in front of the `for` loop and altered `rho = m / _ * 1000` to `rho.append(m / _ * 1000)`.

Comment: Thank you again, @vurmux! You have no idea how much I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Debug your function by adding this print command and you will see that the parameter vol is not a list.

```
print(type(vol))
```

Thus change your code from;

```
OLD: elif isinstance(vol, (list,)):
NEW: elif isinstance(vol, (tuple,)):
```

Comment: Thank you, @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ. Debugging is a smart idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to already good answer by vumux I would check for base class of tuple and a list like so:

`elif issublclass(vol, collections.abc.Collection)`

or

`elif issublclass(vol, collections.abc.Iterable)`

Depengding on your specific needs of course, so for example you know you can iterate through what was passed.

So you can pass anything that inherits from a collection

Comment: Thank you, @mrangry777. I will always appreciate different alternatives so that I am ablet to learn more.